# Executing a function on datetimes generated randomly each day for each user

Tags: python, ios, datetime, heroku, scheduled-tasks

An interesting conundrum. Here's what I want to do:

I have a Pyramid (python 2.7.2) website running on Heroku which pushes notifications to my iPhone app users. Each day, every user needs a push notification sent to them at a randomly generated time between 10:00am and 10:00pm (it obviously needs to know the users timezone as well).

My current plan is the following: Use a persistent worker process to trigger a function every 1 minute on the minute. Each minute, it will call a function (on a different thread so as not to interrupt the timer) which will do 2 things:

1. Check if it's 11:00pm for each timezone (which will happen 24 times a day, once for each timezone). If true, it will call a function which loops through every user in that respective timezone and generates their random time for the next day, then stores it in the Mongo database.
2. On each minute, the worker will also loop through the users and check if they have their notification due at that time. If it's due, then send the notification.

My question is: Is there a better way of doing this that doesn't require generating a huge list of random datetimes every day beforehand?

Comment: Is it important that the time looks random from each individual user's perspective, or would it be OK to send email to Alice every day at 4 PM and Bob every day at 5 PM, so long as the users are spread out throughout the day?

Comment: The time needs to be random for each user every day, so it should not repeat. It must be random and also appear random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly other ways. Whether they're better is a different matter. For instance: suppose there are *n* minutes left before the end of a given user's day and they haven't had their notification yet. Then send them a notification now with probability 1/*n*. This way, you don't need the huge list of random datetimes, but every minute you still need to iterate over all your users, see whether they've been notified yet, and compute random numbers for them all. It's a little more computation in total (though I doubt the difference is significant) and means that all your database updates are small.

Or: Each time you notify a user, *then* you generate their next update time. That way, the next-update times get computed incrementally but are still known in advance.

(If your number of users is relatively small, so that on most minutes there isn't a notification, you can make the scheduling smarter -- but I won't say more about that, because if you have that few users then the amount of work your software needs to do is going to be negligible anyway and there's no point optimizing for that case.)

Comment: `For instance: suppose there are n minutes left before the end of a given user's day and they haven't had their notification yet. Then send them a notification now with probability 1/n.` I like this. Alongside this, what would be a good way to check if they've had their notification yet?

Comment: Put that information in your database. Update it when you send the notification, and at the start of their day. ... Hmm, that does mean that there'll be a big update every hour after all. I think I'm liking the "when you send one update, schedule the next one" scheme better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
Once per PERIOD (e.g. 1 minute) in the RANGE:
    Let NOTECOUNT be the number of users needing notification
    Let FRACTION be the length of the RANGE divided by the PERIOD
    Notify FRACTION of users (either first N or randomly chosen)
    Update notified user records with the notification time

At the end of each RANGE:
    Notify all users whose last notification time is at least 24 hours ago
```

There's nothing explicitly there about how to handle multiple time zones; you could simply consider each supported time zone to require one "instance" of the above process, and the list of users in each time zone would be the candidate list in each instance.  Two potential issues are that users may change time zones, and that time zones suck, so some times may occur twice (e.g. when DST changes), so you should think about that.

Comment: I thought a bit about using a fraction of users...but my math skill isn't great and I'm worried about users slipping through the cracks due to uneven divisors and remainders. Is this a concern?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the double timezone DST gotcha?

Comment: When DST changes over, once a year you "skip" an hour, and once a year you "redo" an hour.  I'm not sure it'll be a problem in  your case since the granularity you're working at (one day) is so much bigger than one hour, but you should keep it in mind.